# Showthat $\mathrm p \leftrightarrow \mathrm q$ and $(\mathrm p\wedge \mathrm q) \vee (\neg \mathrm p \wedge \neg \mathrm q)$ are logically equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Given there are 3 logical variables p, q . Show that $(\mathrm p \wedge \mathrm q) \vee (\neg\mathrm p \wedge \neg\mathrm q)$ and $\mathrm p \leftrightarrow \mathrm q$ are logically equivalent without using the truth table.

And here is my steps: $(\mathrm p \wedge \mathrm q) \vee (\neg\mathrm  p \wedge  \neg\mathrm  q)$

I get this. What should I do in order to get rid of it??
ps: i am studing from Discrete mathematics and its application 7th edition rosen
Thanks.

Comment: What tools (other than truth tables) do you have at your disposal?

Comment: have to answer usingLogical Equivalences
Involving Conditional Statements.

Comment: x @JAWA: Please edit your question to include a precise description of the tools you have. It doesn't help us to see the _name_ your textbook happens to _call_ those tools by; we need to see the tools themselves.

Comment: Are you familiar with distributivity ((p ^ q) v r = (p v r) ^ (q v r)) for logic operators? If yes, use that (or a truth table, although it's not recommended)

Comment: But in question there is no variable r exist then how to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{cl}
& \left(p\land q \right)\lor \left(\neg p \land \neg q\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \left(\left(p\land q \right)\lor\neg p\right) \land \left(\left(p\land q \right) \lor \neg q\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \left(\left(p\lor \neg p \right)\land\left(\neg p\lor q \right)\right) \land \left(\left(p\lor\neg q \right) \land \left(q \lor \neg q\right)\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \left(1\land\left(\neg p\lor q \right)\right) \land \left(\left(p\lor\neg q \right) \land 1\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \left(\neg p\lor q \right)\land \left(p\lor\neg q \right)  \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \left(p \Longrightarrow q\right) \land \left( q\Longrightarrow p \right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \left( p\Longleftrightarrow q\right)
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be answered logically. If you think at what means

$$\phi \iff \psi $$

you will discover that $\phi$ is true only if $\psi$ is true, conversely $\neg\phi$ is true only if $\neg \psi$ is true and this can be translated in symbol as:

$$ (\psi\wedge\phi) \lor(\neg\psi \wedge\neg\phi)$$

Those Equivalence can also be useful if you want to trie something else:

- $\psi \implies \phi $ $\equiv$ $\neg \psi \lor \phi$
- $\psi \wedge \phi \equiv \neg(\psi\implies\neg\phi)$
- $\psi \wedge \phi \equiv \neg(\neg\psi\lor\neg\phi)$
- $\psi \lor \phi \equiv \neg\psi\implies \phi$
- $\psi \lor \phi \equiv \neg(\neg\psi\wedge\neg\phi)$